# clavos con WPF en c#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Public Sub NotificarCambio(ByVal Propiedad As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propiedad))
End Sub
```

Este es en **Visual Basic** ¿Cómo seria en **c#**?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void NotificarCambio(string Propiedad)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propiedad));
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Puede usarse el operador Elvis valiéndonos de `this`? Por ejemplo: `this?.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propiedad))`.

Answer (score 3):

@gerry a mi me sirve mucho esta pagina me puede convertir de vb a c# o viceversa este es el link espero te sirva :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

converter.telerik.com

```
public void NotificarCambio(string Propiedad)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propiedad));
    }
}
```